# Using a parent class with subclasses

Tags: objective-c

I have been doing some reading and a little bit confused, let me explain.

**My situation:**

ClassA.h has some arrays, and ClassA.m has some methods that uses these arrays.  I also have ClassB, ClassC, ClassD... that have their own arrays, and their own methods that use these arrays.  Up until now I have just been copying and pasting the code into each class.

**What I want to do:**

I did some reading and found that I want to create a parent class, where all the methods are housed, and then use these methods in my classes:

```
//parentClass.m
@implementation parentClass

+ (void)commonMethod:(id)sender{

...

}

@end


//classA.m

@implementation classA

- (void)someMethod{
    [parentsClass commonMethod];
}

@end


//classB.m

@implementation classB

- (void)someMethod{
    [parentClass commonMethod];
}

@end
```

**The Problem:**

So I moved the methods to the parentClass.m, and the arrays to the parentClass.h.  My problem is when I try to build and run, I get errors like `Instance variable <someArray> accessed in class method`.  I am not sure what to do.  Is the only way around this problem to declare my arrays above the `@interface` in the `.h` file?

---

EDIT:  The reason I want to use this technique for using methods in the parent class is because I would like to call the methods like this:

`[commonClass commonMethod];`

And not have to declare an instance of the parent class every time.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of inheritance, you have to use *instance* methods (and not *class* methods) if you want to access instance variables, like your array. An instance method is indicated by a `-` (minus) before the method signature, while class methods use a `+`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am still confused.  Are you saying I should change the `+` to a `-` ?  Would I still be able to preform the method call in the same fashion?  To make my problem more clear, I don't want to have to coyp and paste the methods and arrays into every new .h/.m file I create

Comment: You should really read some introductory material. To answer your question though, yes, you should change `+` to `-` in the parent class. You'd then call `commonMethod` simply like this: `[self commonMethod]`. This works because the child classes inherit all methods from their parent class and you can call them as if they were implemented directly in the child class.